# freecodecamp calculator not passing all tests 15/16 - test 14 failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[calculator](https://codepen.io/john-freecodecamp-portfolio/pen/KKVxOgw)

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to get all tests to pass, test 14 specifically:
14. 'Pressing an operator immediately following "=" should start a new calculation that operates on the result of the previous evaluation.'
error:'Uncaught TypeError: currentNumber.charAt is not a function (pen.js:174)
Error: Uncaught TypeError: currentNumber.charAt is not a function (pen.js:174)')
The problem is that after = is pressed and then an operator, the operator isn't being added to current number. The code that's not working correctly is contained in 'else if (this.isCharacter(buttonName))...

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      currentNumber: "0",
      equalsFlag:false,
      decimalFlag:false,
      lastChar:'',
      secLastCharAt:''
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     this.isCharacter = this.isCharacter.bind(this);
    this.isNumber = this.isNumber.bind(this)
  }
  
  isNumber(buttonName){
    if (buttonName === "0"||buttonName === "1"||           buttonName === "2"||buttonName === "3"||
        buttonName === "4"||buttonName === "5"||           buttonName === "6"||buttonName === "7"||
        buttonName === "8"||buttonName === "9")
    {return true}
   
       
 }
isCharacter(buttonName)
  {
    if (buttonName === "+" ||
        buttonName === "-" ||
        buttonName === "*" ||
        buttonName === "/")
      {
        return true;
      }
  }


  
 
  
  
  
  handleClick (event)  {
    let buttonName = event.target.name;
    let currentNumber = this.state.currentNumber
    let operatorFlag = this.state.operatorFlag
    
    if(this.isNumber(buttonName))
        if(this.state.currentNumber!=="0"){
        currentNumber += buttonName
        operatorFlag = false
        }else{
        currentNumber = buttonName
        }
   
    else if(this.isCharacter(buttonName)){
      this.setState({decimalFlag:false})  
      
      if (currentNumber!='0'){
      var lastChar = currentNumber.charAt(currentNumber.length-1)}
      else {lastChar ==' '}
      if(currentNumber.length>=2){
      var secLastChar = currentNumber.charAt(currentNumber.length-2)}
      else{secLastChar = ' '}
      
      
      
      if(currentNumber==='0'){
         currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName 
       }
    
      else if(this.isNumber(lastChar)){
        currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName
      }
     
      else if ((lastChar==='+'||lastChar==='*'||lastChar==='/') 
         &&(buttonName==='-'))
         {
          currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName
         }
      
      else if((lastChar==='-')&&(secLastChar==='+'||secLastChar==='*'||secLastChar==='/')){
        currentNumber = currentNumber.slice(0, currentNumber.length-2) + buttonName
      }
  else if(this.state.equalsFlag){
        //currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName
        this.setState({equalsFlag:true})
      }
      this.setState({currentNumber:currentNumber})
        }
      
    
    else if (buttonName === "AC")
      {
          currentNumber = "0"
          operatorFlag = false
          this.setState({decimalFlag:false})
      }  
       
      else if (buttonName === "=")
      {
          currentNumber = eval(currentNumber)
          operatorFlag = false
          this.setState({decimalFlag:true, equalsFlag: true, currentNumber:currentNumber})
      }
       else if(buttonName === ".")
         {
          if(!this.state.decimalFlag){
            currentNumber += "."
            this.setState({decimalFlag:true})
          }
       }
        
    this.setState({operatorFlag})
    this.setState({currentNumber})
  } 
  
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
        <div id="calcGrid">
        <text id="display"> {this.state.currentNumber} </text>
        <button id="zero" name="0" onClick={this.handleClick}> 0 </button>
        <button id="one" name="1" onClick={this.handleClick}> 1 </button>
        <button id="two" name="2" onClick={this.handleClick}> 2 </button>
        <button id="three" name="3" onClick={this.handleClick}> 3 </button>
        <button id="four" name="4" onClick={this.handleClick}> 4 </button>
        <button id="five" name="5" onClick={this.handleClick}> 5 </button>
        <button id="six" name="6" onClick={this.handleClick}> 6 </button>
        <button id="seven" name="7" onClick={this.handleClick}> 7 </button>
        <button id="eight" name="8" onClick={this.handleClick}> 8 </button>
        <button id="nine" name="9" onClick={this.handleClick}> 9 </button>
        <button id="clear" name="AC" onClick={this.handleClick}> AC  </button>
        <button id="equals" name="=" onClick={this.handleClick}> = </button>
        <button id="decimal" name="." onClick={this.handleClick}> . </button>
        <button id="add" name="+" onClick={this.handleClick}> + </button>
        <button id="subtract" name="-" onClick={this.handleClick}> - </button>
        <button id="multiply" name="*" onClick={this.handleClick}> * </button>
        <button id="divide" name="/" onClick={this.handleClick}> / </button>
        </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}




React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Every string has a `charAt` method, because `String.prototype` has a `charAt` method. Therefore, if "`currentNumber.charAt` is not a function", `currentNumber` cannot be a string. You need to figure out where in your code `currentNumber` is being set to the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

eval() returns a number, so charat() produced an error since it's a string method; adding toString() wherever you update currentNumber via setState fixes the issue.

```
this.setState({
      decimalFlag:true, equalsFlag: true, 
      currentNumber:currentNumber.toString()
})
```

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      currentNumber: "0",
      equalsFlag:false,
      decimalFlag:false,
      lastChar:'',
      secLastCharAt:''
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     this.isCharacter = this.isCharacter.bind(this);
    this.isNumber = this.isNumber.bind(this)
  }
  
  isNumber(buttonName){
    if (buttonName === "0"||buttonName === "1"||           buttonName === "2"||buttonName === "3"||
        buttonName === "4"||buttonName === "5"||           buttonName === "6"||buttonName === "7"||
        buttonName === "8"||buttonName === "9")
    {return true}
   
       
 }
isCharacter(buttonName)
  {
    if (buttonName === "+" ||
        buttonName === "-" ||
        buttonName === "*" ||
        buttonName === "/")
      {
        return true;
      }
  }
  
  handleClick (event)  {
    let buttonName = event.target.name;
    let currentNumber = this.state.currentNumber
    let operatorFlag = this.state.operatorFlag
    
    if(this.isNumber(buttonName))
        if(this.state.currentNumber!=="0"){
        currentNumber += buttonName
        operatorFlag = false
        }else{
        currentNumber = buttonName
        }
   
    else if(this.isCharacter(buttonName)){
      this.setState({decimalFlag:false})  
      
      if (currentNumber!='0'){
      var lastChar = currentNumber.toString().charAt(currentNumber.length-1)}
      else {lastChar ==' '}
      if(currentNumber.length>=2){
      var secLastChar = currentNumber.charAt(currentNumber.length-2)}
      else{secLastChar = ' '}
      
      
      
      if(currentNumber==='0'){
         currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName 
       }
    
      else if(this.isNumber(lastChar)){
        currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName
      }
     
      else if ((lastChar==='+'||lastChar==='*'||lastChar==='/') 
         &&(buttonName==='-'))
         {
          currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName
         }
      
      else if((lastChar==='-')&&(secLastChar==='+'||secLastChar==='*'||secLastChar==='/')){
        currentNumber = currentNumber.slice(0, currentNumber.length-2) + buttonName
      }
  else if(this.state.equalsFlag){
        //currentNumber = currentNumber + buttonName
        this.setState({equalsFlag:true})
      }
      this.setState({currentNumber:currentNumber.toString()})
        }
      
    
    else if (buttonName === "AC")
      {
          currentNumber = "0"
          operatorFlag = false
          this.setState({decimalFlag:false})
      }  
       
      else if (buttonName === "=")
      {
          currentNumber = eval(currentNumber)
          operatorFlag = false
          this.setState({decimalFlag:true, equalsFlag: true, currentNumber:currentNumber.toString()})
      }
       else if(buttonName === ".")
         {
          if(!this.state.decimalFlag){
            currentNumber += "."
            this.setState({decimalFlag:true})
          }
       }
        
    this.setState({operatorFlag})
    this.setState({currentNumber})
  } 
  
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
        <div id="calcGrid">
        <text id="display"> {this.state.currentNumber} </text>
        <button id="zero" name="0" onClick={this.handleClick}> 0 </button>
        <button id="one" name="1" onClick={this.handleClick}> 1 </button>
        <button id="two" name="2" onClick={this.handleClick}> 2 </button>
        <button id="three" name="3" onClick={this.handleClick}> 3 </button>
        <button id="four" name="4" onClick={this.handleClick}> 4 </button>
        <button id="five" name="5" onClick={this.handleClick}> 5 </button>
        <button id="six" name="6" onClick={this.handleClick}> 6 </button>
        <button id="seven" name="7" onClick={this.handleClick}> 7 </button>
        <button id="eight" name="8" onClick={this.handleClick}> 8 </button>
        <button id="nine" name="9" onClick={this.handleClick}> 9 </button>
        <button id="clear" name="AC" onClick={this.handleClick}> AC  </button>
        <button id="equals" name="=" onClick={this.handleClick}> = </button>
        <button id="decimal" name="." onClick={this.handleClick}> . </button>
        <button id="add" name="+" onClick={this.handleClick}> + </button>
        <button id="subtract" name="-" onClick={this.handleClick}> - </button>
        <button id="multiply" name="*" onClick={this.handleClick}> * </button>
        <button id="divide" name="/" onClick={this.handleClick}> / </button>
        </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```